# Singly-linked list insertion in C (pointer to pointer)

Tags: c, linked-list

There are two versions of singly linked list insertion function.

One is common version using one pointer and it's easy to understand:

```
void insert(struct node *newt) {
    struct node *node = head, *prev = NULL;
    while (node != NULL && node->data < newt->data) {
        prev = node;
        node = node->next;
    }
    newt->next = node;
    if (prev == NULL)
        head = newt;
    else
        prev->next = newt;
}
```

Another one is using pointer to pointer :

```
void insert(struct node *newt)
{
    struct node **link = &head;
    while (*link && (*link)->data < newt->data)
        link = &(*link)->next;
    newt->next = *link;
    *link = newt;     //confuse me
}
```

I am confused about `*link = newt;` Although I assign newt to *link, the previous node still point to the 
original address?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inserting a node at the front, you must update the list's head. When inserting after that, you must update the `next` field of the previous node. Using a pointer to node pointer does that:

At first:

```
struct node **link = &head;
```

Now `link` is a pointer to the head pointer. If you update `*link`, you update the head through that pointer.

Later:

```
link = &(*link)->next;
```

Now `link` is a pointer to the current node's `next` field. If you update `*link`, you update that `next` field.

In both cases, if you read from `*link`, you get the current node.

Answer (score 1):

> the previous node still point to the original address?

In `*link = newt;` it assigns `newt` to previous node's `next` member.

`link` either points to `head` or to previous node's `next` member.